# UILabel Position different than expected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, uilabel

Im starting to dabble a bit with swift and ran into a weird behaviour and was wondering if someone could shed some light on why. Im trying to add a UILabel to a UIView and position it in the centre of the UIView. Theoretically this can be achieved with the following.

```
    self.titleContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.origin.x, y: self.view.bounds.origin.y
        + 20.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: (self.view.bounds.height * cSixth) - 20.0))
    self.titleContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(titleContainer)

    self.titleLabel = UILabel()
    self.titleLabel.text = "Naughts and Crosses"
    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10)
    self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.titleLabel.center = titleContainer.center
    titleContainer.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
```

however this doesn't seem to take in the top margin. however the next block of code work and positions the label in the center.

```
    self.titleContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.origin.x, y: self.view.bounds.origin.y
                + 20.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: (self.view.bounds.height * cSixth) - 20.0))
    self.titleContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(titleContainer)

    self.titleLabel = UILabel()
    self.titleLabel.text = "Naughts and Crosses"
    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10)
    self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleContainer.bounds.midX, titleContainer.bounds.midY)
    titleContainer.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Alec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing coordinate systems. `self.titleLabel.center` is a point inside `titleContainer` and `titleContainer.center` is a point inside `[titleContainer superview]`.

The differences are explained in the **[View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6)** -> **View and Window Architecture** -> **View Geometry and Coordinate Systems** -> **The Relationship of the Frame, Bounds, and Center Properties**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want the label to sit at the center point of `[titleContainer superview]` so surely that works? I apologise i don't really see the difference?

Comment: I have added a link that tries to explain the differences.